# How to prove that no two-to-one function can be continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

This is question

[image]

I have almost done this question, but why can we only assume $a<c<d\leq b$ and why not $a\leq c<d<b$ and also the case when $a=c$ and $b=d$. That is my professor asked me, could you explain for me?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that since at least two of $c, d, e, f$ are in the interior of $[a, b]$, we must have:

- EITHER at least one of $c, d$ is in the interior of $[a, b]$,
- OR at least one of $e, f$ is in the interior of $[a, b]$.

(Of course, perhaps both possibilities hold.)

Each possibility further refines into two more possibilities: e.g., if we have that at least one of $c, d$ is in the interior of $[a, b]$, then

- EITHER $c$ is in the interior of $[a, b]$ - in which case $a<c<d\le b$ -
- OR $d$ is in the interior of $[a, b]$ - in which case $a\le c<d<b$.

(Again, perhaps both possibilities hold.)

So we know that (at least) one of the following **four** cases holds:

- $a<c<d\le b$,
- $a\le c<d<b$,
- $a<e<f\le b$, or
- $a\le e<f<b$.

The point is that each of these cases is handled in the same way, so we only have to explicitly write out one of them.

That said, you should understand **why** they are each handled in the same way - look at the proof of the "$a<c<d\le b$" case, and see why $(i)$ nothing special about "maxima" (vs. "minima") is used, and $(ii)$ why nothing special about the left extremum being in the interior (vs. the right extremum being in the interior) is used.

Comment: Could you explain the last paragraph please? I don't really understand. Thanks!

Comment: @HuZi So, look at the argument that follows the assumption that $a<c<d\le b$. See if you can modify it very slightly to work under the assumption, for instance, that $a\le c<d<b$ . . . (HINT: basically, just "flip everything around," so $a$ and $b$ switch, $c$ and $d$ switch, etc.)

Comment: So the way to prove the assumption a<c<d<=b is the same as the assumption a<=c<d<b? Can I write the conclusion directly?