# Number of discontuinity Two to one functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let's call a function $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ Two to one if for any $y \in Im(f)$ there is exactly two distinct $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y$

Is it true that every Two to one function with **domain $\mathbb{R}$** must have infinite number of discontinuity?

P.S: As answered before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541989/how-to-prove-that-no-two-to-one-function-can-be-continuous) it must be discontinous but can it have finite number?